# E-mail doesn't arrive! HELP

Tags: php, drupal, email, mime-mail

I'm having an issue with sending an order e-mail from Drupal (Ubercart).

I actually don't think the issue is in Drupal, because the e-mail is sent correctly to my e-mail address, but it doesn't arrive to the company e-mail address.

What I've done so far to understand what's th issue:

- I received an e-mail from Drupal on my address (so drupal + server can send e-mails.. everything works)
- I've sent an e-mail to the company address (It works)
- I removed the spam filter on the other e-mail address (Nospam filter disabled).
- I'm waiting the end of the day, hoping in a server lag.. but I don't think so because I did point 2 and it arrived immediately...

any tip ?
Thanks

**Update**: Server logs:

```
2010-07-27 17:48:02 1OdmNu-0005fT-As <= o110334@hostingservice.com U=o110334 P=local S=25369 T="New order" for companyaddress@company.com
2010-07-27 17:48:02 1OdmNu-0005fY-Da <= o110334@hostingservice.com U=o110334 P=local S=1050 T="New Order" for companyaddress@company.com
2010-07-27 17:51:28 1OdmRE-0006fr-NQ <= o110334@hostingservice.com U=o110334 P=local S=25377 T="New order" for companyaddress@company.com
2010-07-27 17:51:28 1OdmRE-0006fv-OJ <= o110334@hostingservice.com U=o110334 P=local S=1052 T="New Order" for companyaddress@company.com
2010-07-27 18:04:15 1Odmdb-0002C9-63 <= o110334@hostingservice.com U=o110334 P=local S=822 T="New order" for myaddress@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some email is getting through, it is probably not a drupal or php problem. Check your mail server logs.

Comment: I've asked for the log and I posted it in my question. It seems that the e-mails are effectively sent by the server to both addresses, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't sweat it too much. This is pretty normal on a new server, especially if the company have a filter somewhere. These kind of things usually work themselves out on a day or two if it's actually working, which seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

These questions will help troubleshoot the problem....

Is the email hosted on different server as website and carries same domain name as website?

Is Drupal able to send email to company email?

Looks to me email is not leaving the server (DNS issue).

***Add MX DNS Record on Webserver pointing to company Mail Server.

Comment: 1) The company e-mail is on different server. Also my gmail account (for testing) is on different server. The first doesn't work. The second works.

Comment: 2) No, that's the issue. Drupal can send an email to me (on gmail), but not to the company e-mail

Comment: Is the sender specified in the e-mail important ? I've just specified a not existent address.. something like no-reply@companyname.com ... I dunno if this might cause problems.

Comment: "***Add MX on Webserver pointing to company Mail Server." I dunno what this means. thanks

Comment: MX DNS Record(mail exchanger record). If your server running linux is most likely running bind DNS. You'll need to add this entry in Bind to direct mail to the domain in question which is this case is elsewhere. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've asked for the mail log and I've added it to the question. I guess the e-mail is sent, then. I've disabled spam filters on the company mail, still nothing.. what can I do ? Should I ask the mail log to the other server as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take at look at this Atwood post:

[So You'd Like to Send Some Email (Through Code)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)

A brief summary:

1. Make sure the computer sending the email has a Reverse PTR record
2. Configure DomainKeys Identified Mail in your DNS and code
3. Set up a SenderID record in your DNS